# how to you catch an exception only in main?

Tags: java, exception

I have a file which i will open in another class.In my operations with that file i will need exceptions.How can i treat them ONLY in main and just throw them ?pls give me the syntax i have been trying for 2 days and i don't get the idea.everytime i open the folder i need to do a try catch and catch it in that function and i want to catch it in main.

Comment: Which language? What is the error message? Could you post some code, what you already tried?

Comment: add a `throws` declation to the methods, where you don't want to handle the exceptions. Assuming this is a Java question.

Comment: yes the language is java,i'm sorry i didn't specify.There isn't any error message,the program works well,but i needed to catch the exception just in main ,and until them throw them around.

Comment: @DianaLc You should (almost) always tag language.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the exception in other class and catch that exception in main method with try catch block.

```
import java.io.*;  
class SearchFiles{  
 void method()throws FileNotFoundException{  
  throw new FileNotFoundException("file not found");  
 }  
}  


public class ThrowsTest{  
   public static void main(String args[]){  
    try{  
     ThrowsTest t=new ThrowsTest();  
     t.method();  
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("exception handled");}     

    System.out.println("normal flow...");  
  }  
}
```